# EventHandler not capturing resourceChangedAttributes and resourceAddedAttributes filtered events in AEM 6.4

Tags: aem, eventhandler

We have implemented an Event Handler registered as below:

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingConstants;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.observation.ResourceChangeListener;
import org.osgi.service.event.Event;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventConstants;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


/**
 * This is a node observer class which would observe the path /content/we-retail
 * for any addition or updation of nodes (type = cq:PageContent). 
 * @author 
 */

@Component(label = "Test Event Listener", immediate = true, metatype =
    false, enabled = true)
@Properties({

   /* @Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, value = ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC)
            })*/

    @Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, value =
        {"org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource/ADDED",
            "org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource/CHANGED"}),
    @Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_FILTER, value = "(&" +
        "(path=/content/we-retail/us/en/*/jcr:content) (|(" + SlingConstants
        .PROPERTY_CHANGED_ATTRIBUTES + "=*jcr:title) "
        + "(" + ResourceChangeListener.CHANGES + "=*jcr:title)))")
})

@Service(EventHandler.class)
public class TestEventHandler implements EventHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestEventHandler.class);

    /*
     * Reference of ResourceResolverFactory object.
     */
    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resourceResolverFactory;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler#handleEvent(org.osgi.service.event.Event)
     */
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        LOG.info("Hi event is called ......");
    }

}
```

**Issue is: Our handleEvent doesn't get trapped when change the property value for jcr:title on any page under the path: /content/we-retail/us/en**

AEM version is: 6.4
sling version used is : org.apache.sling.api

Comment: My gut says there is something wrong with the actual event filter you setup. Have you verified that you can see the change events in the /system/console/events console? If you see them there, the suspicion of a wrong filter is confirmed.

Comment: @hbtolearn - Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.0.6 (Sling API Bundle 2.0.6) it is deprecated.
You should implement `org.apache.sling.api.resource.observation.ResourceChangeListener`
please see the sample: [ResourceChangeListener sample](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/events/impl/SampleResourceChangeListener.java)

Comment: ResourceChangeListener does not solve the problem. It's methods like getChangedPropertyNames() are also deprecated, because 'the application code can not rely on getting the correct set of changed properties. A resource provider implementation is free to not support this.'